# Pytest got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

Tags: elasticsearch, pytest, fastapi

I'm trying to test my FastAPI endpoints that involve creating sources in elasticsearch:

```
def make_test_source(
    client: TestClient,
    name: str = "test-source",
    quantize: bool = False,
    embedding_model: EmbeddingModel = EmbeddingModel.TEXT_EMBEDDING_ADA_002,
    **kwargs,
):
    return client.post(
        url="/api/v1/sources",
        json={
            "source": name,
            "contains_secret_data": False,
            "adct_id": "ADCT-12345",
            "embedding_model": embedding_model,
            "quantize": quantize,
            **kwargs,
        },
    )

@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_create_source(es, client):
    make_test_source(client=client, name="test-source")
    assert await es.indices.exists(index="test-source")
    assert "test-source" in (await get_global_sources(es))
```

I have the following fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def anyio_backend():
    return "asyncio"


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app = create_app(test=True)
    app.dependency_overrides[get_user] = get_user_override
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c


@pytest.fixture
async def es(client):
    """Initialize Elasticsearch client and database.

    Sets up metadata and permissions indices and removes all indices
    after each test.

    Pass this function to every test case that uses Elasticsearch, even
    if it doesn't call the ES client directly.
    """
    _es = connections["es"] 
    await create_metadata_index(_es)
    await create_permissions_index(_es)
    yield _es
    await clear_all_indices(_es)
```

`/app/v1/sources` looks like:

```
@router.post(
    path="/",
    summary="Create a new source",
    status_code=HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_source(
    body: CreateSourceRequest,
    user: Annotated[User, Depends(required_user)],
    es: ElasticSearchDep,
):
    embed_dims = embedding_models[body.embedding_model].embed_dim
    quantize = body.quantize
    try:
        # --- where the error occurs ---
        await es.indices.create(
            index=body.source, mappings=get_document_mapping(embed_dims, quantize=quantize)
        ) 
    ...
```

I'm also using FastAPI's lifespan feature to persist the connection with elasticsearch in a separate `apps.py` file:

```
connections = {} 

@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan_test(app: FastAPI):
    connections["es"] = AsyncElasticsearch(
        hosts=[
            {
                "host": "0.0.0.0",
                "port": 9200,
                "scheme": "https",
            }
        ],
        basic_auth=("elastic", settings.ES_TEST_PASSWORD),
        verify_certs=False,
        ssl_show_warn=False,
    )
    yield
    await connections["es"].close()


def create_app(test: bool = False):
    app = FastAPI(title="test", lifespan=lifespan_test)
    
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["*"],
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
        expose_headers=["*"],
    )
    app.add_middleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware, dispatch=catch_exceptions_middleware)
    app.include_router(router)

    return app


app = create_app()
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='starlette.middleware.base.BaseHTTPMiddleware.__call__.<locals>.call_next.<locals>.coro' coro=<BaseHTTPMiddleware.__call__.<locals>.call_next.<locals>.coro() running at /Users/.../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py:151> cb=[TaskGroup._spawn.<locals>.task_done() at /Users/.../venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py:661]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

I think it might have something to do with the fact that I'm making a call to elasticsearch inside the POST request, but I thought that it is using the same connection via the connections dictionary. Would really appreciate any help on this.